# java.lang.ClassCircularityError: java/util/ArrayList$ListItr when instrumenting JDK

Tags: java, instrumentation, runtimeexception, javassist

I am trying to instrument JDK classes. I  was able to instrument classes like java.lang.System and java.lang.Thread. However, over 370 classes fail with an error :
java.lang.ClassCircularityError: java/util/ArrayList$ListItr.

It seems that any class that is dependent or reference java.util.ArrayList$ListItr cannot be instrumented due to this problem.

Here is snippet of where the exception appear:

```
ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
CtClass ctClass = classPool.makeClass(className)//Here everything goes wrong :(;
```

Any ideas about that :(

Comment: Isn’t `makeClass` for generating entirely new classes? How does this relate to instrumenting existing classes? Besides that, you forgot to mention *what* you are actually doing. “instrument JDK classes”, well yes, what kind of changes do you apply and what kind of Instrumentation do you use, load time or hot replace, etc.

Comment: One of things I am doing is measuring execution time for each method. Thus, I insert currentTimeMillis ay the beginning and end of each method invocation.

Comment: This snippet is inside a transormer class. So, the method returns ctClass.getBytes().

Comment: But afaik, `makeClass(String)` starts with a fresh new class, so you’d drop all existing all code instead of transforming it. But besides that, if you do this inside a load-time transformer class, your transformer might get called again for all classes used internally by the method (and all other classes subsequently used by Javassist), if these classes had not been loaded yet. That would create a circular dependency. So you can’t transform *all* classes this way.